# Does Newton’s third law of motion apply to time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have a question about how physics works. I am asking about what the law applies to, not about whether this effect could be experienced, so please don’t answer “it doesn’t matter because causality prohibits time travel”. This might be the case, but the law might still work in this was. And please don’t state that I’m “ignoring the laws of physics”, because I am not.

Newton’s third law of motion basically states that when you produce a force in one direction, it produces an equal force in the opposite direction. Given that time is also a dimension, if something had advanced technology that allowed it to exert force along the temporal axis, would Newton’s law still apply?

Comment: *assuming causality isn't a factor..* so throwing out what we know of causality being a cornerstone of physics?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the idea of a "dimension" here.

Comment: @Triatticus I was asking a question about physics, whether it could ever come into play is irrelevant, so whether causality matters is irrelevant as well.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I am not, it just works differently. Time is a dimension just like space, but events in time are based on certain things. If an object were placed below another object it would not break the object above it. This is not the same with time, as individual frames have an influence on frames above them.

Comment: No it's more that, you are asking what physics says.....while ignoring the actual laws of physics. How can physics say something if you are already throwing out the laws of physics.

Comment: I was asking about how physics works, and I didn’t want people to think I was asking for a hypothetical situation, because otherwise the answer would almost certainly be “it couldn’t work because causality”, instead of a real answer. I was not throwing out laws of physics. It could be the case that it works to that extent, but does not matter because of causality.

Comment: Concerning v2: Are you asking if Newton's third law applies to an action-reaction force pair at non-equal times?

Comment: Let’s just say you have a piece of technology that can exert force in the temporal axis. Would this make the object travel through time in the opposite direction, or does Newton’s 3rd law only apply to spacial dimensions?

Comment: That was basically what I was asking. My question was already answered though, so I know that it is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have misunderstood the concepts. Newton's third law is all about how forces interact. When one object pushes or pulls another, the second object pushes or pulls back with the same strength but in the opposite direction. This law doesn't really touch on the nature of time itself.

Imagine you're playing with toy cars. When one car bumps into another, the second car might move or even bump back because of the impact. This bumping back-and-forth is like Newton's third law.

Now, talking about time in this scenario would be like discussing how long you've been playing with the toy cars. It's a separate concept. It doesn't change how the cars bump into each other, just like Newton's third law doesn't really explain how time behaves. Time, in this case, is just the background against which all these car interactions are happening.

Comment: You are right. Time is a dimension, but there is never really any motion, just continuous objects. If an object were to move in time, its shape would change because events would change. This means that since objects in time have a dynamic shape, motion doesn’t really exist in the dimension of time.

Comment: @WhatsYourIQ192 Welcome to SE. "This means that since objects in time have a dynamic shape, motion doesn’t really exist." I am not sure what is that supposed to mean? What is the "dynamic shape" objects in time have, or objects have in time...?

Comment: Well, if an object were to ever truly move in time (like the object’s conception and destruction were moved forward in time), then events would change, and so would its shape in time.